# My quicksort in Python3 is breaking the recursion limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, quicksort

```
from random import *
from time import *
import sys


def quicksort(mylist, pivot, end):
    # pivot will always be the first element in the list/sub-list
    if (len(mylist) == end) and (pivot == 0):  # shuffle the list before we start (only happens on the first call)
        shuffle(mylist)
    if (pivot == end) or (pivot == end-1):
        return mylist
    sr = pivot + 1  # start from element after pivot
    sl = end - 1  # start from end of list
    smaller = None
    bigger = None
    smallest_index = 0

    while sr <= sl:
        if mylist[sr] > mylist[pivot]:
            bigger = mylist[sr]
        else:
            sr += 1
        if mylist[sl] < mylist[pivot]:
            smaller = mylist[sl]
        else:
            sl -= 1
        if (sr < sl) and (smaller is not None) and (bigger is not None):
            mylist[sr] = smaller
            mylist[sl] = bigger
            smallest_index = sr
            sr += 1
            sl -= 1
            smaller = None
            bigger = None
        if (sr-1 == sl) and ((smaller is not None) or (mylist[sl] <= mylist[pivot])):
            smaller = mylist[sl]
            smallest_index = sl

    mylist[smallest_index], mylist[pivot] = mylist[pivot], mylist[smallest_index]
    quicksort(mylist, pivot, smallest_index)
    quicksort(mylist, smallest_index+1, end)
    return mylist
```

I also used sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000) because it was originally breaking the limit with larger lists, but I end up getting exit code 0xC00000FD

I've been working at this for hours and just can't seem to crack it. I can't tell if I just need a better implementation or if I went wrong somewhere. This was the only implementation I could come up with unfortunately.

Help please?

Comment: can you try to run this code for your set of data and let me know if it works..  `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-quicksort/`

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola it works fine without even having to change the recursion limit, thanks. I'd rather not use this specific code though, I'd like to know how to better my current implementation

**EDIT:** Maybe I could adapt my code using this actually, but this uses the last element in the list as the pivot instead of the first element like I'm trying to use and that's confusing me a bit (on how to alter it)

Comment: If this is homework, you probably should tell us that.  If you just need to order a list, python's built in Timsort is excellent and influential. If you want to see an assortment of lists in Python for academic purposes, you could look at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/

Comment: @dstromberg it's not homework, I'm self-taught atm. The way I learned to understand quicksort was using the first element as the pivot, so I'd like to implement it that way for now at least just to better understand the algorithm.

Comment: `import *` is bad practice, be careful!